# How to stop playing notification sound programmatically on Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I create notification using notification builder like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
String someString = "StackOverflow is the best";
builder.setContentTitle(someString)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setLights(0xFF00FF00, 500, 3000)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
Notification notif = builder.build();
Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
      notif.sound = soundUri;
      AudioAttributes.Builder attrs = new AudioAttributes.Builder();
      attrs.setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION);
      attrs.setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE);
      notif.audioAttributes = attrs.build();
} else {
      builder.setSound(soundUri, AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
      notif = builder.build();
}

notif.flags = notif.flags & (~ Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT);
return notif;
```

Problem is that I can't stop playing sound, until opening Notification Panel. I need to stop this sound with click on power button. I created service, that detects *android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON* and *android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF* actions:

```
public class StopNotificationSoundService extends Service {
  private BroadcastReceiver sReceiver;

  public IBinder onBind(Intent arg) {
      return null;
  }

  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startIs) {
      IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
      filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
      sReceiver = new StopSoundNotificationReceiver();
      registerReceiver(sReceiver, filter);
      return START_STICKY;
  }

  public void onDestroy() {
      if (sReceiver != null)
          unregisterReceiver(sReceiver);
      super.onDestroy();
  }
```

}

And here is *broadcast receiver*:

```
    public class StopSoundNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          Log.d("LOG_TAG", "StopSoundNotificationReceiver");
          // Here is code that stops sound
      }
  }
```

Help me with this, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab instance of NotificationManager:

```
    NotificationManager notify_manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Save somewhere ID of your notification and call

```
    notify_manager.cancel(your_id);
```

Or you can remove all notifications:

```
    notify_manager.cancelAll();
```

Comment: Is it stops the sound, or removes notification from notification bar at all?

Comment: @AndriiChernysh how did you solve this, I have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

```
notificationBuilder.setDefaults(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this post is more than 5 years old, I wanted to add that the accepted solution will remove the notification entirely, not just end the sound, and that a notification can't be canceled if it is started by a ForegroundService and that foreground service was not stopped/destroyed.

The solution that I found for stopping sound from a notification programmatically such as when the user clicks the power button, was to decouple the sound from the Android Notification in the first place and instead have the ForegroundService control that.

Example code

```
class ForegroundServiceThatPlaysSound : Service() {

  private var ringTone: Ringtone? = null

  private val stopSoundOnPowerButtonBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver by lazy {
    object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            ringTone?.stop()
        }
    }
  }

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    registerReceiver(stopSoundOnPowerButtonBroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))
  }
  
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    startForeground(id, createNotification(callerName)
        )
 try {
        
     ringTone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
            applicationContext, RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                application,
                RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE
            )
        )

        ringTone?.play()
        
    } catch(e: RuntimeException) {
        //Do some error logging
    }
    return START_STICKY
}

 override fun onDestroy() {
    ringTone?.stop()
    ringTone = null
    unregisterReceiver(stopSoundOnPowerButtonBroadcastReceiver)
    super.onDestroy()
}
 
private fun createNotification(callerName: String) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val newChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, channelImportance).apply {
            lockscreenVisibility = lockScreenVisibility

            //Sadly you have to do this if you have a channel with DEFAULT importance or higher
            setSound(null, null)

            //Interestingly enough vibration is already dismissed on screen off
            if(shouldEnableVibration) {
                vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0L, 1000L, 500L, 1000L)
                enableVibration(true)
            }
        }
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(newChannel)
    }
    
    return NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NAME_OF_YOUR_CHANNEL)
        .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
        .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
        .setContentText(contentText)
        .setOngoing(true)
        //Priority is ignored in Android 8+ and it will go by channel importance
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        //Just like in Channels you sadly need to do this too for < Android Oreo
        .setSound(null)
        //setVibrate is ignored in Android 8+ and it will go by channel
        .setVibrate(longArrayOf(0L, 1000L, 500L, 1000L))
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        //...etc
        .build()
}
```

}